# How to configure LDAP client to authenticate against ApacheDS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ldap, apache-ds

I am playing with LDAP lately and trying to authenticate against ApacheDS. I am unable to setup my Ubuntu client to print the LDAP users list (`getent passwd` for instance). I found few tutorials on the web of how to setup the server side. I do that via the Apache Directory Studio and have no issues at all - the server is up and running, the Studio sees the users and groups I got there. I am using the example `apache_ds_tutorial.ldif` from Apache DS website. 
I found some LDAP client setup on the Web, all made for OpenLDAP. I tested that one too and successfully authenticate against it. However, when I try to set it up in similar way for my ApacheDS it won't work.

Does anyone know how I could setup my LDAP client for ApacheDS?
Thanks!

Comment: Whats the error you get ? The setup is the same for any ldap directory

Comment: I got correct output from `ldapsearch -x` but `getent passwd` does not display LDAP users.

Comment: I think I got it. It turned out the `cn=nis,ou=schema` was disabled by default and the ObjectClass posixAccount was not available. As soon as I enabled it, I was able to create test user and to login as such. Thanks!